# Access function defined in MyApp() class - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to access a function defined in my top level class from another class. How can i do that ?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> 
{
  
  void startListeningNotifications()
  {
    //start listening to fcm messages
  }


  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
    
    startListeningNotifications(); 
  }  
}
```

I want to call this function **startListeningNotifications()** from another class. Is that possible ?

I am already calling this function in **initState()** but there are some cases in which i need to call it from some other class. For example, if a user isn't already registered with your Firebase-app, then after the registration process, i need to access this method in order to start listening to fcm notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `startListeningNotifications()` in a different file, import it into any page you need and call it there.

```
// create lib/_utils/fcm_utils.dart
void startListeningNotifications() {
  // your function
}
...



// main.dart or any page you want to call your functions from
// TODO: replace yourAppName below with your app name
import 'package:yourAppName/_utils/fcm_utils.dart';
...
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  startListeningNotifications(); 
}
```

Comment: Well yes i can do that but aren't FCM implementation need to be in the top level class?

Comment: ` FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await notificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
  ?.createNotificationChannel(channelAndroid);`

Isn't the code is supposed to be in the top level class ?

Comment: This function `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);` should be in your main (and only called once), while `firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` should be a top level function in your main. Then `await notificationsPlugin...` can be defined in any file.

Comment: ```await notificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
  ?.createNotificationChannel(channelAndroid);
```
You mean this one can be called from anywhere ?

Comment: What about the channel?
`const AndroidNotificationChannel channelAndroid = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', //id 
  'High Importance Notification', //name
  'This channel is used for important notification', //description
  importance: Importance.high,
  sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('sound')
  );`

Does this one needs to be on the top level too or it can be defined anywhere and then be called in the main()

Comment: yes, both of them can be called from anywhere.

Comment: Also, what about checking if user has successfully logged in. I am using Provider model for accessing and storing data but i can't access context property in this function to use the Provider model. `Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message)`.  Currently, i am using a class with Provider model and updating a bool property when user successfully logs in. If i create an instance of this class then definitely it's bool property is false by default and it should be. What can be the way of making it a central data class or anything like that.

Comment: I do not think you need to check for login there. This is mine: `Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {await Firebase.initializeApp();}`  But if you want to know if the user has  loggedIn, then you can't use Provider, you can use get a service locator like get_it (https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) to access your bool (login) property from anywhere in the code. You should ask this as a fresh question so other users can benefit.